# This app has reached its outbound request limit

Tags: sharepoint-addin, requestexecutor

I am getting "This app has reached its outbound request limit" error when do more than two simultaneous calls using SP.WebProxy in my SP-hosted app. Do you know whether it is possible to change this threshold in AppManifest or in some other place? Or queuing is the only solution? I have SP2013 on-premises.

PS: I've found several similar questions on the Internet, but all of them are without the answer.

Comment: @MkihailSP Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Just answered in the answers section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I workaround the issue by doing calls using queue in my app.

I put a request object in the queue and the other part of my app gets the first object from the queue, trying to do a call, if it fails, it tries again after some time. After call is succeed, it resolves the promise of the related request object with the result and processes the next request from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are facing is related to the throttling rules of SP2013.

I think you need to modify the and configure Request Management of the servers in the farm.

I think this is a good article for and will hopefully resolve your problem

http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2013rm2.aspx

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Manish. Unfortunately, I believe that the issue isn't related to Request Management. I looked through the article you proposed. It is a great article, but it seems there is no mentioning of something similar to my issue. I am experiencing problem when using the SharePoint cross-domain library, which helps to overcome the same-origin policy.